# What is the function of "overlay" value of "overflow" property?

Tags: css, overflow

I am unable to understand the difference between "overlay" & "auto".
Does "overlay" does the same work as "auto"?

Comment: Don't even concern yourself with `overlay`, it's non standard and does the same as `auto`. Concern yourself with [standard values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Answer (score 42):

The only difference is that `overflow: overlay` is only supported by -Webkit browsers, is non-standardized, and allows the content to extend beneath the scrollbar - whereas `overflow: auto` will not allow the content to extend beneath the scrollbar, if it appears it'll occupy the space required and shift the content accordingly (either vertically or horizontally).

```css
p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12em;
    height: 5em;
    border: dotted;
}

p.overflow-auto { overflow: auto; /* append scrollbars if necessary and shift content accordingly to accommodate */ }

p.overflow-overlay { overflow: overlay; /* append scrollbars if necessary and overlay over/above content */ }
```

```html
<p class="overflow-auto">overflow: auto
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>

<p class="overflow-overlay">overflow: overlay
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
```

The above snippet demonstrates the difference as follows:

```
p.overflow-auto { overflow: auto; /* append scrollbars if necessary and shift content accordingly to accommodate */ }

p.overflow-overlay { overflow: overlay; /* append scrollbars if necessary and overlay over/above content */ }
```

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap with a fixed navbar, then a vertical scroll bar will offset the body content but not offset the fixed navbar, giving you a pixel-alignment error in that case. overflow:overlay stops the scroll bar having that effect, in Chrome-based browsers.