# What is alternate for overflow:overlay css property in mozilla and internet explorer browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

`overflow:overlay` is working fine in chrome and safari. This property isn't available in IE and Mozilla browsers. I need the scroll bar pane to be visible always.

Comment: my advice: don't use deprecated functionality ... according to MDN *This deprecated API **should no longer be used**, but will probably still work* - though, it only ever "worked" in webkit

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050434/what-is-the-function-of-overlay-value-of-overflow-property

Comment: [Official Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by in the comments above and in the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

> This deprecated API should no longer be used, but will probably still work.

However, since you mentioned:

> I need the scroll bar pane to be visible always.

You can use the value `overflow: scroll`, and you will always have the scrollbar whether or not any content is actually clipped, and this will prevent the content from moving and changing your layout, for example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse dictum ligula vel dolor eleifend, vel interdum risus tristique. Nullam laoreet sed metus at aliquam. Aliquam ornare sagittis nibh in volutpat. Sed dolor orci, viverra ut lectus ac, commodo faucibus nisl. Proin molestie felis ligula, ullamcorper sollicitudin lacus commodo eu. Curabitur sit amet cursus ante. Aliquam vel leo et justo luctus semper eget sit amet turpis. Aenean ac rhoncus dolor. Etiam ut euismod arcu, vehicula suscipit ex.   Donec nec posuere sapien. Phasellus accumsan sem nec nibh congue, ut porttitor diam convallis. Nulla ac tempus arcu. Suspendisse at lorem est. Nullam sit amet commodo felis. Quisque ac mollis metus. Duis varius eleifend sem, eget venenatis ante mattis
  at.
</div>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse dictum ligula vel dolor eleifend, vel interdum risus tristique. 
</div>
```