# Transparent Scrollbar Is Not Rendering Child Items Behind It

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, transparent

I have a div that has the "overflow" property set to "overlay".  I have modified the scrollbar track to be transparent.

I'm able to view the background elements of the web page just fine, however, I'm encountering an issue when viewing elements inside of the div with the scrollbar.  When an element goes behind the scrollbar, it doesn't render the part of the element that goes behind the scrollbar.  This would make sense for a scrollbar that's not transparent (why bother wasting time rendering something that will just be covered?).  However, because the scrollbar track is transparent, it should make sense to still be able to see the elements behind it.

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050434/what-is-the-function-of-overlay-value-of-overflow-property

Comment: You can see some examples here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200639/transparent-scrollbar-with-css

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez I already understand the difference between overlay and auto.

Comment: @Donada That link explains how to make the scrollbar transparent.  I'm passed that step.  I'm trying to render the elements that are covered by the overlayed scrolltrack (which is transparent, so I would want to be able to see items behind something that's transparent)

Comment: Please post the code that created the transparency, and any other code that could be relevant to the issue. This might help us to help you >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I know this is kinda old, but were you using `background-attachment: fixed`? Because I got the same problem with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905430/why-does-setting-background-attachment-to-fixed-change-the-width-behaviour-of-th