# Why does setting background-attachment to fixed change the width-behaviour of the background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've built a Fluent-Design like scrollbar with CSS and JS ([github repo](https://github.com/timlg07/Fluent-Design/tree/master/scrollbar)). The scrollbar normally works fine, but when setting the `background-attachment: fixed` for the element containing a background image (the body or any child) it breaks: If I change the scrollbars width by making it partially transparent, the transparent region is rendered white (the bodys background-color) and the image is not continued to be displayed behind the scrollbar; And if I change the scrollbars width directly ([source](https://github.com/timlg07/Fluent-Design/tree/scrollbar-improvement-width/scrollbar)) the backgrounds width changes while the elements width stays completely the same (=> the element is continuing behind the scrollbar, but its background is not).

Here's a short example of what I mean:

(1) Working properly without `background-attachment: fixed`:

```html
<script src="https://tim-greller.de/git/fluent/scrollbar/scrollbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://tim-greller.de/git/fluent/scrollbar/scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="light" style="background: linear-gradient(50deg, #fde6a5, #fac1f8);">
  <div id="content" style="height: 200vh">
    content
  </div>
</body>
```

(2) Now with the background fixed, which shows only white behind the transparent parts of the scrollbar:

```html
<script src="https://tim-greller.de/git/fluent/scrollbar/scrollbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://tim-greller.de/git/fluent/scrollbar/scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="light" style="
            background: linear-gradient(50deg, #fde6a5, #fac1f8);
            background-attachment: fixed;">
  <div id="content" style="height: 200vh">
    content
  </div>
</body>
```

edit: using https links.

Comment: What browser are you using? On my Firefox 80.0b6 the scrollbars on both of your examples look exactly the same.

Comment: @derw That's because the scrollbar-styling is limited to webkit (when you look into the source code of my scrollbar.css, you'll see the webkit selectors for scrollbars). You're just seeing the default scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed in the current Chromium versions.