# Div size in Internet Explorer 11, doesn't work

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have an Angular Application which should work also in IE11: how can I write an equivalent to the following instruction but valid also for IE11?

```
overflow-y: overlay;
max-height: calc(100vh - 195px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was the following:

1) In main style file:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

2) In the specific div:

```
style="height: calc(100% - 100px); overflow-y: overlay;"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: since when is `overlay` a valid value for `overflow`?

Comment: @cloned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050434/what-is-the-function-of-overlay-value-of-overflow-property (Maybe this value is not so actual)